# Verifying solutions to equations containing roots.

Tags: complex-analysis

<Edited to eliminate confusion between roots of an equation and (square) roots of a number.>

What does it mean for a complex number to be a solution to an equation containing square roots? Since an expression with square roots is multi-valued, is an equation containing square roots even well defined? For example X - X^(1/2) + 1 = 0. I think that the solutions are CIS(2pi/3) and CIS(4pi/3). However, substituting any potential solution, c, into the equation gives 2 different equations to verify, because there are 2 possible values for c^(1/2) (unless c=0). CIS(2pi/3) satisfies the equation using CIS(pi/3) as its square root, but not using CIS(4pi/3) as its square root. CIS(4pi/3) satisfies the equation using CIS(5pi/3), but not using CIS(2pi/3) as its square root.

Is c considered a solution to an equation with square root(s) if there is any choice of square root values for which c satisfies the equation? Seems more and more absurd as the number and degree of square, cube, fourth ... roots in an equation grows.

Comment: Your final question is difficult to understand. As for the first question, it means the same thing as a real number. IIRC, a root of $f$ is just a value $x$ such that $f(x) = 0$. This is true for both real and complex numbers.

Comment: When working with noninteger powers of complex numbers, you have to pick a branch of the complex logarithm and either stick to it or keep very good track of when you move to another one.